# Select all checkboxes in a list generated by a database query

Tags: php, jquery

My logic is (obviously) off, but here's what I have...

When a purchase request is approved, it goes into a list for our "purchaser" person who drives into town to get the items (I live in rural Alaska, so this is a big deal).  All of the items, regardless of purchase request, are dumped into foreach loop per vendor. In other words, there could be 10 purchase requests, but all Home Depot items go in a Home Depot table.

I'd like to have a box that checks "mark all as purchased" per vendor, so when someone leaves the store, they can just mark that they got all the Home Depot items.

Here are my problems. 
1. It doesn't always work.
2. When it does work, you only get 1 shot at it. Once you click it, you have to refresh the page to get that function to fire again.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
$suppliers = [];
$suppliersQ = $db->query("SELECT supplier FROM purchase where status = ?  ORDER BY supplier",array('approved'));
$suppliersC = $suppliersQ->count();

//Did we find anything? Get a list of the vendors we need to visit
if($suppliersC > 0){
  $suppliersR = $db->results();
  foreach ($suppliersR as $key=>$value){

    if(!in_array($value,$suppliers)){
      array_push($suppliers,$value);
    }
  }
} else {
}

if(!empty($_POST['purchased'])){
  foreach($_POST['purchased'] as $k=>$v){
    $fields = array(
      'status' => 'purchased',
      'purchased_by' => $user->data()->fname." ".$user->data()->lname,
      'purchaser_id' => $user->data()->id,
    );

    $db->update('purchase',$v,$fields);
  }
}

if(!empty($_POST['removed'])){
  foreach($_POST['removed'] as $k=>$v){
    $fields = array(
      'status' => 'removed',
      'purchased_by' => $user->data()->fname." ".$user->data()->lname,
      'purchaser_id' => $user->data()->id,
    );

    $db->update('purchase',$v,$fields);
  }

}

?>

<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Content goes here -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3 align="center"><a href="purchaser_all_pr.php?closed=0">View All PRs</a></h3>

      <form class="" action="purchaser.php" name="buildings" method="post">
        <input class='btn btn-danger' name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit' class='submit' />
        <?php
        if($suppliersC > 0){
          foreach ($suppliers as $k=>$v){

            $purchaseQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE status = ? AND supplier = ? ORDER BY will_call,payment",(array('approved',$v->supplier)));
            $purchases = $purchaseQ->results();
            ?>
            <div class="table table-responsive">
            <table class='table table-hover' >
              <h4><?=$v->supplier?>(<a href="purchaser_print.php?vendor=<?=$v->supplier?>">Print</a>)</h4>
              <p align="right"><input type="checkbox" id="<?=$v->supplier?>"/> Mark all purchased</p>

              <tr>
                <th>WC?</th>
                <th>Method</th>
                <th>Item #</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>QtyMin</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Est Total</th>
                <!-- <th>Actual Total</th> -->
                <th>Purchased?</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
                <th>PR</th>

              </tr>
              <?php

              foreach ($purchases as $purchase){
                ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="vendor.php?id=<?=$purchase->supplier_id?>"><?=$purchase->will_call?></a></td>
                  <td><?=$purchase->payment?></td>
                  <td><?=$purchase->item_num?></td>
                  <td><?=$purchase->item_desc?></td>
                  <?php
                  //Costco show description instead of link
                  if ($purchase->supplier_id == 10){ ?>
                  <td><?=$purchase->link?></td>
                <?php }else { ?>
                    <td><a href="<?=$purchase->link?>">Link</td>
                <?php } ?>
                    <td><?=$purchase->qty?></td>
                    <td><?=$purchase->qty_min?></td>
                    <td><?=$purchase->price?></td>
                    <td>$<?=$purchase->est_tot?></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="<?=$purchase->supplier_id?>" name="purchased[<?=$purchase->id?>]" value="<?=$purchase->id?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="removed[<?=$purchase->id?>]" value="<?=$purchase->id?>"></td>
                    <td><a href="view_pr.php?prid=<?=$purchase->pr?>">PR-<?=$purchase->pr?></a></td>

                  </tr>
                  <SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#<?=$v->supplier?>").click(function () {
          $('.<?=$purchase->supplier_id?>').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".<?=$purchase->supplier_id?>").click(function(){

        if($(".<?=$purchase->supplier_id?>").length == $(".<?=$purchase->supplier_id?>:checked").length) {
            $("#<?=$v->supplier?>").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#<?=$v->supplier?>").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
                  <?php
                }
              }
            }
            ?>

          </table>
        </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Content Ends Here -->
      </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div> <!-- /.wrapper -->


<?php require_once $abs_us_root.$us_url_root.'users/includes/page_footer.php'; // the final html footer copyright row + the external js calls ?>

<!-- Place any per-page javascript here -->


<?php require_once $abs_us_root.$us_url_root.'users/includes/html_footer.php'; // currently just the closing /body and /html ?>
```

Comment: you should be using `.prop('checked'...` not `.attr('checked'...` . This was changed way back in jQuery 1.6. That might be part of the problem. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I changed it to prop and removeProp. Still not working. It's just intermittent. It's not throwing any errors in the console.  If you look at this screenshot, it fires for the top vendor (amazon) but not for the second one.http://puu.sh/uLEWk/ac27a734db.png

Comment: removeProp actually removes the property entirely, which would then cause problems later on. To check a box, it's `.prop("checked", true);`, and to uncheck a box, it would be: `.prop("checked", false);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment.  I have achieved similar by looping the checkbox list in. Jquery. Something like this:

```
$(checkboxlist).each(function (){
  $(this).prop('checked',true)
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to fire either. I think I'm going to have to give each checkbox the vendor's id (dynamically) and get that same function to check all boxes with that id.  I just don't think in javascript yet, so I need to work that out in my brain.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of this:

```js
$(function() {
  // first select all
  $('#first .select-all').click(function() {
    if ($('#first .select-all:checked').length == 0) {
      $('#first input[type="checkbox"].option').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
    $('#first input[type="checkbox"].option').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
  
  // second select all
  $('#second .select-all').click(function() {
    if ($('#second .select-all:checked').length == 0) {
      $('#second input[type="checkbox"].option').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
    $('#second input[type="checkbox"].option').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
  
  // for your purposes you can remove this timeout
  // I've only added it so you know that it works
  setTimeout(function() {
    var options = $('#second .option');
    var totalCheckboxes = options.length;
    var checked = 0;
    
    options.each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
      {
        checked++;
      }
    });
    
    if (totalCheckboxes == checked)
    {
      $('#second .select-all').prop('checked', true);
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Here I'll show you how to select and deselect all checkboxes-->
<div id="first">
  <input type="checkbox" value="all" class="select-all"> Select all <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option"> Option 1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="option"> Option 2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="option"> Option 3 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="option"> Option 4 <br>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- In this I'll show you how to select the "Select all" checkbox if all the other checkboxes are selected -->
<div id="second">
  <input type="checkbox" value="all" class="select-all"> Select all <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="option" checked> Option 1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="option" checked> Option 2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="option" checked> Option 3 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="option" checked> Option 4 <br>
</div>
```

No offense but your code is horrible you should consider using MVC framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

Comment: I will give that a whirl.  And offense taken :)   This project is built on UserSpice, which is definitely not as polished as Laravel, but does the job.